# Need Assistance for this Htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my `.htaccess`, a short explanation I would like to set `http://example.com/newest` on my website. However, it always redirects to `http://example.com/postname`. Where I just need the exact "newest" page. Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/category/(.*)$ page.php?f=$1
RewriteRule ^/search/(.*)$ search.php?f=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ post.php?f=$1 <- If this is removed, my post htaccess will not work
RewriteRule ^newest/$ index.php?f=newest <- I want to execute this code
```

I really don't know what this is called, I have been looking for the whole stackoverflow but I did not get any answer. Please remain me if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: did you try to put it above post line? this line RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ post.php?f=$1  will catch any request before coming to  this line RewriteRule ^newest/$ index.php?f=newest

Comment: I did before but it did not work. I think ^(.*) will catch all parameter without any limit. So I think it must be an algorithm to limit it but I don't know what should be used.

Comment: do search and category go normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mohammed implied in comments, your directives are in the wrong order. The line above your "newest" rewrite is a catch-all and rewrites all requests, so the last line will never match.

> ```
> http://example.com/newest
> ```

Note that your rules imply that your URLs should end in a trailing slash. So, you should be linking to `http://example.com/newest/` (with a trailing slash), not `http://example.com/newest`, otherwise your users will get a lot of unnecessary redirects.

However, you appear to be under the belief that the `RewriteCond` directive applies to all the directives that follow. This is not the case. It only applies to the first `RewriteCond` directive. You also need some `L` flags to prevent further processing.

You also have a slash prefix on the "category" and "search" rewrite *patterns*, so these would never match in a `.htaccess` context.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Don't process the request further if it maps to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Append trailing if omitted
# Although strictly speaking this only redirects if there are no slashes at all in the URL
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ page.php?f=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?f=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^newest/$ index.php?f=newest [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ post.php?f=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works, could you please to explain what is it for?
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

Comment: That `RewriteRule` (together with the `RewriteCond` directive that precedes it) prevents any further processing of the mod_rewrite directives that follow, if the request maps to a file. The `^` _pattern_ matches all URLs and the `-` (a single hyphen) _substitution_ does not change the URL. Note that this is the opposite of your directive (note the missing `!` prefix on the _CondPattern_), which only executes the following directive if it does not map to a file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Anyway thanks for your answer as it is really helpful for me. I get a new knowledge again :)